# copying data from on XML file to another

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to copy the content from one XML file( items.xml) into another xml file(product.xml) where available='yes", by using xsl.  How can I do that?  I have the follwoing XML file

item.xml:

```
<items>
    <item available="yes" >
        <name> laptop  </name>
        <quantity>  2 </quantity>
    </item>
    <item available="yes" >
        <name> mouse </name>
        <quantity> 1 </quantity>
    </item>
    <item available="no" >
        <name> keyboad </name>
        <quantity> 0</quantity>
    </item>
</items>
```

output:

```
<items>
  <item>
    <name> laptop </name>
    <quantity> 2 </quantity>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name> mouse </name>
    <quantity> 1 </quantity>
  </item>
  <item available="no">
    <name> keyboad </name>
    <quantity>0</quantity>
  </item>
</items>
```

Answer (score 1):

The XSLT you need is simply the identity rule with an additional template for the ones you want to remove, that generates no output.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="item/@available[.='yes']" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The first template is more specific, and will override the more general template below.

Comment: yeah it works but if i need element tags also in output as above then what changes should be made in xsl

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by saying "by using xsl if available" ?
However the only way to acoomplish your goal is to parse it. 
It depends by the technology you use, in Java for example I there are several way to parse an XML file: DOM, SAX, STAX. 
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<xsl:import>` or `<xsl:copy>`  to achieve this.

Comment: adding the missing part.you can use xsl:import or xsl:copy tags in xsl